# Whats the best way to serve twitter bootstrap from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I've read some blog articles about setting up a basic template using twitter bootstrap and serving it from nodejs. There seems to be a lot of ways to achieve this using express and jade or another render engine.

My questions are what is the best way to do this? Are some render engines better than others?

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks in advance Ric

Comment: Your question and your title don't match.  You are asking about mass convert in the question but serving in the title..

Comment: Ok updated it and will ask the other question later on. Thanks Shane

Comment: Not good to ask "Are some render engines better than others?". It may create controversy here.. So till its removed down votes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861961/static-content-nodejs

Answer (score 10):

I use Express and Jade on Heroku with my projects and I use Twitter Bootstrap. Since Twitter Bootstrap is just a couple of css files and javascript plugins, your question doesn't really make sense. Twitter Bootstrap isn't different than including any other type of library you use on your web pages, so really you're asking how to serve pages in Node.js.

Just lookup the syntax for including files in jade [here](http://jade-lang.com/) and then learn how to serve pages on Heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is Embedded JavaScript.  Lightning fast and you won't have to learn a new syntax.