# Static Content & NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I saw many articles showing how NodeJS can serve static content, [like this](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/5/6/serving-static-files-from-node-js), basically, they use Node to read the file and return the result. I don't think thats the right way? It seems inefficient? Also how do I detect the right content type (CSS, JS etc)? Is there a proper way of doing this?

Comment: If app you writing not going to production (e.g. homework, or you just playing with node), add some memory-cache (or use redis) and it will be ok. If you writing something serious, use specialized module (JohnnyHK's answer) or framework even — save yourself some time, don't reinvent bycicle.

Comment: I recommend to use nginx as the static content holder. It should be faster and simpler and reduce unnecessary load from your node server which need to do some business processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to use one of the node modules that already exist for static file serving such as [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) or [node-static](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static).